# Как добавить зависимость RecyclerView в build.gradle?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method implementatio() for arguments [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0] on object of type [image: введите сюда описание изображения]org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы добавляете не ту зависимость.

Относительно недавно произошёл переезд библиотек из пакета `com.android.support` в `androidx`. Соответственно библиотеку recyclerview надо подключать так:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```